# Setting CLASSPATH permanently

Tags: java, linux, classpath

In order to set my classpath environment variable, I'm running the following command:

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/to/appropriate/dir
```

In order to check that this was correctly set, I'll type

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

and am returned /path/to/appropriate/dir.

However, when I open up a new tab or window in the terminal

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

returns nothing. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable you set in a terminal, is valid only for that terminal. What you should do is, export the variable in your `~/.bashrc` file, which is loaded for each terminal. So, add that statement in the `.bashrc` file, and you'll be fine.

You can also export the variable from `~/.bash_profile` file, which will be loaded for login shells.

Answer (score 0):

for bash, add the following lines to this file (~/.bashrc):

PATH=[your path]:$PATH
export PATH

for more details check
[PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Type nano .bashrc
   2.Go to the end of line and type ->export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar(It is the location where you have stored .jar file that you have downloaded).
   3.It becomes permanent now

Comment: This answer adds nothing that other answers have not already said, and makes assumptions about what path the OP wanted to add to their `CLASSPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

After you set the CLASSPATH variable in you `~/.bashrc` file remember to enter `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal.