# Java classpath is not there after restart machine

Tags: java, macos, selenium-webdriver

I have installed java , JDK and everything on my MAC machine. I have set classpath using below command :

> export
>   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_06.jdk/Contents/Home/

Now If I do from terminal : **echo $JAVA_HOME** , it prints above classpath

BUT after restart machine if I do **echo $JAVA_HOME** , it prints nothing and blank , what could be issue? Classpath is set properly or not?

Comment: You will have to set it permanently. Please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21078868. In general you want to write the `export` somewhere in your profile ([ref](http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/07/what-is-profile-file.html)), which is loaded every time you restart.

Comment: @Kariem - I have already read that answer but they have not explained in details that how to set class path with `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Oh, ok. Just edit your `~/.bashrc` file and put the line you have at the end of the file or where you see it fits best. When you restart and use bash, it should be loaded. However, if you are using a different shell than bash, it's better to add this line to `~/.profile` (see Link in previous comment)

Comment: @Kariem - thanks , finally I did it :)

Comment: OK. Great! Good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put below line in your `~/.bash_profile` as you are using mac, for linux its `~/.bashrc`

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_06.jdk/Contents/Home/`

Comment: what is actually `~\.bash_profile?` how can I reach to that?

Comment: Put that command line in file /etc/profile for machine wide. See details here : [link](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-mac-os-x-terminal-only/)

Comment: just type on terminal `vi ~/.bash_profile` and hit enter, then copy paste your export var in that and `:wq` thats all